# How to display two items a string and an Image in Xamarin Picker control?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, picker

I have a situation where I need to display a picker control in Xamarin like the following way.[image]

Where it will display the country Flag and Country code side by side.
And the selected country code should display as the background image of the Picker control. (As in the image)

I have just started with `Xamarin` and found that Picker doesn't have `ItemSource` property like WPF XAML and it doesn't support `DataTemplate` too.

Using a `listView` I can achieve this but `ListView` Control and Picker controls usability are different.

Can anybody guide me how can I achieve this feature in Picker in `Xamarin-XAML`?

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Are you having trouble using the listview control or just looking for confirmation that its ok to use it?

Comment: Sorry for my English, I don't have any problem using ListView. But How to show the same itemList in a picker control. A Picker Control that will display the Country code and Country flag. Like the image in the question.

Answer (score 3):

`Picker.Items` is an `IList<string>` so I think you can't do that, because it's made to hold strings only. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Picker.Items/

However you can make another page and on that page place a `ListView` so that the use can set the language there.

Comment: Thanks for the in-detail explanation. I have prepared a ListView Which does what I want.  But how can I popup a list view at runtime?

Comment: @Debhere Do you really have to make the `ListView` "pop up"? Because it's much easier and more elegant to just make another `Page`. This way when the user presses the "Change language" button, the app will navigate to the language page. There the user can change the language easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try that.

Answer (score 1):

A ListView with an ImageCell within the DataTemplate.

Check out Chapter 19, around page 587 of Charles Petzold's eBook.  You can download it from here:

[Creating Mobile Apps with Xamarin.Forms Book First Edition](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/)